# Converting a SQL_ASCII database to UTF-8

Tags: postgresql, encoding

I have a postgresql (version 8.1) database that has the encoding set to SQL_ASCII, combined with several apps that some are running using UTF8 and some with LATIN1. With this scope I have a database with the data divided in LATIN1 and UTF8.

I have the difficult task to deploy a brand new server, running PostgreSQL 9.3 with the database with the UTF8 encoding. But I'm stuck!

Here is what I have tried so far with no success:

- pg_dump forcing UTF8: error converting non-utf8 to utf8
- pg_dump forcing LATIN1: no error during dump or restore, but the characters with accentuation are totally wrong
- pg_dump forcing LATIN1 and conversion with **iconv** to UTF8: same error as above

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow, that's not going to be fun at all. Are the utf-8 and latin-1 data divided cleanly into different tables / schemas? Or are they mixed together in all tables?

Comment: have you tried this approach http://agiletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/postgresql-dumprestore-and.html? they used http://www.gnu.org/software/recode/...

Comment: @CraigRinger it is all mixed together, unfortunately

Comment: @Leo I've tried with **iconv** but I'll give **recode** a shot.

Comment: If it's mixed together you're in a right mess, because pretty much all utf-8 is also valid (if usually weird) latin-1, and some latin-1 is valid utf-8. Personally I'd be doing it on a field-by-field basis with some Python or whatever, using some heuristics based on my knowledge of common characters etc to make a best-guess effort.

Comment: I'm running the **recode** command right now, if it doesn't work I'll try to convert all data to UTF8 (with  [convert](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html) in psql) before dump it all

Comment: Guys, apparently the **recode** did the trick. I am doing some more tests, when I'm done I'll post all the results here. Thanks!